# debugging mpi java

Tags: java, mpi

How does one debug mpijava code. Ideally, I would want to debug it on the same machine with eclipse with a master and a client running and attached to the same eclipse. Though these might be two processes but since eclipse can debug multiple running threads, may be that is possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Run server with options:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8998,server=y
```

Then run eclipse and connect to 8998 port. See [How To Debug a Remote Java Application](http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-debug-remote-java-applicat) for details.